# Which way is the best way to go? duplicate VS using null

Tags: java

I got this project where i am making a new react interface to an java program to freshen up the GUI. But the new GUI still builds on the old backend so i want to use as much code as possible from the old backend in the new interface. But i am faced with this problem that alot of the methods use old GUI components as parameters the most extreme may be this one

```
deploy(unzipDirectory,combobox bla,checkbox bla,button bla)
```

so when is use this method to use in the new gui i need to send

```
deploy(unzipDirectory,null,null,null)
```

and then some if statements to only use the combobox when its not null etc. i feel as this is bad practice but the only solution i see is to rewrite it for my new gui. The problem then is that the old interface is still gonna exsist and be used so then it means i will have two methods which does the same thing if i make a special one for the new GUI, this aswell seems as bad practice because there will be alot of duplicate code. this happens in alot of places so there would be alot of "duplicate" methods or alot of null parameters.

So my question is which way would be the better way of the two? or is there another way to make this in a good practice way?

Comment: it all comes down to TIME, do you have enough time? write clean methods. you don't have enough time? use the old method

Comment: An opinionated answer: Basing new work on old work in a way it was maybe not originally planned to be used in is always ugly. Other than rewriting I don't think there is a clean solution. If you are only payed for "works" then an unclean solution is probably what you need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, if you need to keep compatibility with the old version, I would use method overloading, this way:

```
@deprecated
public deploy(unzipDirectory,combobox bla,checkbox bla,button bla){
    //The logic goes here
}

public deploy(unzipDirectory){
    deploy(unzipDirectory, null, null, null);
}
```

With the `@deprecated` annotation you advise not to use the old method for new method calls. You can migrate all the calls to the new API later on and end up removing the old method, moving the internal implementation to the new one.

Comment: Your example uses the same arguments for both methods and this would result in a compilation error. Edit: now fixed :)

Comment: Shouldn't be the deprecated method that defers to the new one ?. If this is deprecated, the "unused parameters" (send as `null`) would not be used, so one day, when the deprecated annotation would be well noticed and the application will be up to date, we would just need to remove that method. I don't fell that creating a new method that call the deprecated version really logic. (I am just talking about the annotation, not the solution itself)

Comment: @AxelH, sorry but I don't understand what you mean. If you give the dev the choice to call both methods, the dev should prefer the single-parametered choice over the other method one, which is deprecated. Then he knows he shouldn't make method calls using UI components as arguments.

Comment: My point is not about which method to call (seems logic that we should not prefer a deprecated method) but the fact that the new implementation calls the deprecated method. It fells strange to me to mark that old method as deprecated but ignore that and redirect that overloaded method. Basically, I see that like "Do what I say, not what I do".

Comment: Ok.. I see your point. There's still a thing to take into consideration. The way I've written keeps your logic in the old method. You needt to change your old method to accept UI parameters, or not. This parameters would be optional, so as it would accept `null` values, but that doesn't mean you'll completelly avoid them. You need to still keep accepting them and processing them in order to support the old API. You could still make a deeper refactoring, but that implies time, as comments above state. I wrote down the way I consider the fastest, changing the minimal amount of code.

Comment: Like I said, not pointing the solution here, it's the most efficient solution, especially in term of testing! Just the annotation that can be a bit "strange".

Comment: @AxelH while calling a deprecated method from a non-deprecated method might seem bizarre, it's not that clear cut. There are many reasons why a method may be deprecated, including: you shouldn't be calling this method, it's for internal purposes, but we accidentally made it public and now we can't change it anymore.

Comment: Fair enough @Kayaman, I was stuck on the current situation and forgot to see other usage of _deprecated_.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a simple new `deploy` method which has just one argument (just `unzipDirectory`), which then itself handles calling the old `deploy` function and adds the null arguments. This would make writing new code easier and allows for backward compatability. At some point in the future you may have enough time to then remove all the old style function calls.

e.g.

```
public void deploy(String unzipDirectory) {
    deploy(unzipDirectory, null, null, null);
}
```